# Do I need an implementation of a third party interface to be able to complete my code?

Tags: java, interface

I've been given a project to complete, which itself is fairly straight forward.

Basically I have been given an interface called `CourseEligibility`, which I need to implement (`CourseEligibilityImpl`). And there is an external interface available called `CourseExplorer`.

My implemented class will have a method called

```
canEnrollOnCourse(int studentYear, String courseCode).
```

And the external interface has the method called

```
getCourseYear(String courseCode)
```

It's all fairly straight forward, but should I implement the `CourseExplorer` class or how else could I use its abstract method in my `CourseEligibilityImpl` class?

`CourseExplorer`is meant to be an external class, which a different team is supposed to be working on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your CourseEligibility should have a member variable of base type CourseExplorer.  Then it would use any implementation of CourseExplorer.

Comment: How would I write this? I've tried using CourseExplorer courseExplorer, but what do I add on the right side of the = sign? If I leave it as simply CourseExplorer courseExplorer, I can't use any of its methods as it hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Take a CourseExplorer argument in the constructor and initialize in the constructor to that.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot. I completely forgot that method existed!